# Swift: SKNode should have optional types, Optional member does not have member

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I had a working and compiling Swift game before I updated to the new XCode and suddenly a lot of errors has appeared. Here is two I haven't been able to fix.

```
func centerOnNode(node: SKNode ) {

   let cameraPositionInScene = node.scene?.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: node.parent!)

   var y = CGFloat(node.parent?.position.y - cameraPositionInScene?.y!)            
   // ERROR:
   // Operand of postfix ‘!’ should have optional types; Type is CGFLoat

   let x = CGFloat(node.parent.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x)
   // ERROR: 
   // SKNode? does not have a member position

   // push the camera a bit up
   y -= 75

   node.parent.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
```

I guess I don't really get this ! and ? business. Wrapping, unwrapping, optional types. What is this in Java or C# terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, assuming `node.scene` is **never** `nil`, and `node.parent` is **never** `nil`:

```
let cameraPositionInScene = node.scene!.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: node.parent!)

var y = CGFloat(node.parent!.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y)

let x = CGFloat(node.parent!.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x)
```

If it is possible for those to be `nil`, use this code instead:

```
if let cameraPositionInScene = node.scene?.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: node.parent!) {
    if let parent = node.parent {
        var y = CGFloat(parent.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y)

        let x = CGFloat(parent.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x)

        // push the camera a bit up
        y -= 75

        parent.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
    }
}
```

This will test to ensure that none of the values are `nil`, and will do nothing if they are (instead of crashing, as the first example would).

For an explanation of how optionals work, read [Apple's article](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_485).